# Fixing topology errors creates more errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology

I am running topology on a shapefile to fix overlaps/gaps, when I correct some of them, more seem to form when I run validate topology. I think maybe in fixing the errors I am perhaps moving  the shapefiles which is causing a ripple effect. Also is there anyway a newbie GIS user can batch correct topology errors, I have loads of shapefiles I am putting into a set format and obviously none can have topology errors.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you are correcting one overlap/gap that seems to cause more overlaps/gaps when you run validate topology?  A before and after picture would help greatly.

Comment: I am using the fix topology error tool to either subract, merge or create new features. I think the problem comes in along the outer boundary of the shapefile if that make sense, as sometimes there is a small gap there that then runs along as gaps between different habitats, so sometimes I have tried to edit the polygons to close that gap at the boundary. I thought maybe while I am doing that maybe I am changing the shape of the polygon or possibly moving it ever so slightly. Maybe there are tolerances or something I should set?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced unintentionally moving polygons and resolved it by setting a sticky move tolerance of 300 pixels. That made it more difficult to accidentally move the features which caused a topology error. Under Editor Toolbar> Options> General Tab.